# Why won't my gas dryer stay lit?

Tags: repair, dryer

My Amana gas clothes dryer is not heating properly. The gas ignites when the dryer is first started, but after the gas turns off the igniter glows and then turns off, without relighting the gas.

Many websites I found said that this was typically due to bad coils. I removed the coils and tested the resistance across the terminals. The resistances match example values I [found](http://appliancejunk.com/blog/2010/01/22/how-to-test-dryer-gas-valve-coils/).

Could the coils still be defective, or is it more likely that the gas valve is bad?

Comment: This site says that the valves rarely fail and that the coils are typically the cause: http://applianceassistant.posterous.com/the-dreaded-gas-dryer-heating-problem-capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coils were defective. Bought replacements on Amazon and everything's back to normal!

Answer (score 2):

This could be an issue with the thermocouple. A thermocouple is used to sense whether the gas was ignited by the glow coil and is burning. If it isn't burning, and the thremocouple isn't heated up by the flame, the gas valve is shut off to prevent excess gas buildup.

Although this might not be the exact problem, it might lead you down the right path to find it.

Comment: May also be known as `Flame Sensor` or `Flame detector`.  A Thermocouple, is just one type of flame sensor. See [Flame detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flame_detector)

Answer (score 1):

I have a 15 year old Kenmore gas dryer that wouldn’t stay lit. I checked the coils for continuity and they were within spec (I got the spec in ohms from some other website). However, when I had the dryer open to see what was going on, I felt the coils after the flame went on and then off, and one was warm to touch. I decided to replace both coils and the dryer has been working fine over the past 2 months.
If I have the same problem after a decade or so, I’ll replace the coils straight away, since they are inexpensive and easy to get. That is if I remember to :).